# What is the cmd field of the request structure in block layer replaced with?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian, block-device, nvme

I was going through the new kernel code and it looks like the `cmd` field in the `request` [structure](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/blkdev.h#L132) (defined in linux/blkdev.h) doesn't exist anymore. [Here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9.230/source/include/linux/blkdev.h#L178) is what it looked it in earlier versions.

I am using that field to send a specific request structure(`struct nvme_command` to be more specific) down to the block device. How do I update my code to use the latest version of the `blkdev.h`? More specifically, how do I send down my `nvme_command` structure to the block device now that there is no `cmd` field?

Comment: Upstream switched to block MQ implementation.

Comment: https://www.redhat.com/archives/dm-devel/2017-January/msg00121.html